# range windows form textbox C# .net

Tags: c#, windows, textbox

I would like to allow user to enter only a number between 0 to 360. How can I do it using textbox control in my C#.Net windows application ?

Answer (score 3):

Judging from your question history I assume you are talking about c# and the .Net framework. If you want to do that enable the TextBox control Validation property (set it to true)

Then define the validation function

```
private void textBox1_Validating(object sender, 
                System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
   int input = 0;
   bool isNum = Int32.TryParse(textBox1.Text,out input);

   if(!isNum || input < 0 || input > 360)
   {
      // Cancel the event and select the text to be corrected by the user.
      e.Cancel = true;
      textBox1.Select(0, textBox1.Text.Length);

   }
}
```

Comment: Err... I think you meant an `int.Parse()` in there somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to simply check the value when the user hits the submit button. If it's out of range, you can pop up a message.

You can also try and restrict input as the user types, but this can be a little problematic. For example, what do you do if a keystroke makes the result out-of-range? And what happens if the number is temporarily out of range as the user makes a legitimate edit?

Comment: The Validating event takes care of all those cases as it gets fired once the control being edited loses focus. The Validating event as its name implies is the correct event to use when validating input.